# Can't explain jquery error

Tags: jquery

I have written a loop in jquery:

```
var divs=$('#anfragescroll').children();//document.all('anfragescroll').children;
for(i=0;i<divs.length;i++)
{
  alert(divs[i].id);
  var elements=divs[i].children();
  for(j=0;j<elements.length;j++)
  {
    elements[j].prop('disabled',true);//.disabled=true;
  }
}
```

alert() is just called once. The mistake seems to be in the following line. What is wrong? I don't understand it.

```
  <div id="anfragescroll">
    <div id="anrede_gutschein_div">
        <fieldset id="anredefieldset" class="fullwidth">
          <label for="frau">
            <input id="frau" type='radio' name='anrede' value='Frau' onclick="makeRight(this.parentElement.parentElement);"> Frau
          </label>
          <label for="herr">
            <input id="herr" type='radio' name='anrede' value='Herr' onclick="makeRight(this.parentElement.parentElement);"> Herr
          </label>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
    <div id="vorname_name_div">
        <input type="text" id="vornametextinput" class="halfwidth" name="vorname" placeholder='Vorname' onclick="makeEdit(this)">
        <input type="text" id="nachnametextinput" class="righthalfwidth" name="name" placeholder='Name'>
    </div>
    <div id="land_div">
        <select id="landselect" class="halfwidth" name='selectland'>
          <option value='' disabled selected>▼ Land</option>
          <option value='Belgien'>Belgien</option>
          <option value='Deutschland'>Deutschland</option>
          <option value='Liechtenstein'>Liechtenstein</option>
          <option value='Luxemburg'>Luxemburg</option>
          <option value='Österreich'>Österreich</option>
          <option value='Schweiz'>Schweiz</option>
          <option value='anderes Land'>anderes Land</option>
        </select>            
        <input type="text" id="gutscheintextinput" class="righthalfwidth" name="gutschein" placeholder='Gutscheincode (ggf.)'>
    </div>
```

[... and so on]

Comment: share html mark up

Comment: What's not working as you would like it to work? I'm not understanding the problem

Comment: divs.length is 12, so the loop should be iterated more than once. If I push the alert() below the following line, it doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I supose that you have a code like this

```
<html>
    <head>
         <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
       <div id="anfragescroll">
         <div></div>
         <div></div>
         <div></div>
         <div></div>
      </div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var divs=$('#anfragescroll').children();

    for(i=0;i<divs.length;i++)
    {
      alert(divs[i].id);
      var elements=divs[i].children().first();
      for(j=0;j<elements.length;j++)
      {
        elements[j].prop('disabled',true);
      }
    }
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

The error is effectively on the next line because you do not specify the id or class of the div you are running, as this for that function works.

```
$("#"+divs[i].id).children().first();
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It seems a bit illogical for me, but it's the first time I write something in jquery. Now it works.